# How to write Template class copy constructor

Tags: c++, templates, copy-constructor

How to write copy constructor for a template class. So that if the template parameter is another user defined class it's copy constructor is also get called.

Following is my class

```
template <typename _TyV>
class Vertex {
public:
    Vertex(_TyV in) :   m_Label(in){ }
    ~Vertex() { }
    bool operator < ( const Vertex & right) const {
        return m_Label < right.m_Label;
    }

    bool operator == ( const Vertex & right ) const {
        return m_Label == right.m_Label;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Vertex& vertex) {
        return os << vertex.m_Label;    
    }

    _TyV getLabel() { return m_Label;}
private:
    _TyV m_Label;
public:
    VertexColor m_Color;
protected:
};
```

Comment: Do you want to have copy constructor that can accept any `class` as argument ?

Comment: @iammilind: That wouldn't be a copy constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `_TyV` is a value type:

```
Vertex( Vertex const& src )
    : m_Label( src.m_Label )
{}
```

Aren't those names within class instances reserved by the implementation, by the way?

> The C++ standard reserves a set of names for use by C++ implementation and standard libraries [C++ standard 17.6.3.3 - Reserved names]. Those include but are not limited to:
>
> - Names containing a double underscore.
> - Names that begin with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter.
> - Names that begin with an underscore at the global namespace.

Comment: @Avinash: It would work just as well, I don't know why I wrote that. Will fix.

Comment: If it's a reference, you can't make an assignment operator.  If it's a pointer, and you want a deep copy, you'll have to specialize the class.

Comment: Is `Vertex(Vertex const& src)` same as `Vertex(Vertex<_Tyv> const& src)`?

Comment: @Sam: yes, it's called _injected class name_.

Answer (score 4):

Either a) not at all, just rely on the compiler-provided default; or b) by just invoking the copy constructor of the member:

```
template <typename T> struct Foo
{
  T var;
  Foo(const Foo & rhs) : var(rhs.var) { }
};
```

The point is of course that the compiler-provided default copy constructor does precisely the same thing: it invokes the copy constructor of each member one by one. So for a class that's composed of clever member objects, the default copy constructor should be the best possible.

Comment: After seeing your answer, I understood the question. :)

Comment: You can also explicitly default the copy constructor in C++0x. Also this places the `CopyConstructible` requirement on your template argument.

Answer (score 2):

```
template <typename T>
class Vertex {
public:

    //this is copy-constructor
    Vertex(const Vertex<T> &other) 
          : m_Color(other.m_Color),m_Label(other.m_Label)
    {
      //..
    }
    //..
};
```

But I don't think you need to explicitly define the copy-constructor, unless the class have *pointer* member data and you want to make deep-copy of the objects. If you don't have *pointer* member data, then the default copy-constructor generated by the compiler would be enough.

Comment: I do not know how the class will be used. I want to make it generic.